# Лишние зависимости в проекте

Tags: ооп, проектирование

Вопрос в первую очередь к тем, кто уже участвовал в больших проектах. Часто приходится слышать, что лишние зависимости - это плохо. Хотелось бы понять, чем так мешают лишние зависимости в проекте. Я придумал только две причины:

1. Поиск ошибки. Когда ищешь ошибку, есть определенное количество вариантов причины её возникновения. Теоретически, при лишних зависимостях это количество увеличивается.
2. Тестирование. При ненужных зависимостях иногда нельзя применить модульное Mock-тестирование. Хотя это не всегда так, а только в крайних случаях, когда, например, модель зависит от UI.

Какие еще существуют причины, с которыми я еще не столкнулся? Хотелось бы именно причин, а не "ну это не очень хороший стиль", и т.д.

Comment: гибкость, kiss, код реюз, расширяемость и т.д. и т.п.

Дабы не перечислять просто говорят "плохой стиль"

Comment: Хотелось бы именно причин, а не "ну это не очень хороший стиль"

ну и отвечающему хотелось бы по подробнее услышать вопрос

Comment: Что такое "лишние зависимости" ?

Comment: "лишние зависимости" - признак плохо спроэктированной архитектуры. это доставляет массу неудобств при поддержке кода. особенно если на проэкте текучка кадров. отсутствие четко распределенных обязаностей между классами приводит к лавинообразному эффекту, - изменения одного приводит к изменению большинства связанных с ним. снижается читаемость кода, что усугубляет проблему с текучкой кадров.  

p.s. а еще матерные слова становятся самымы употребляемыми  
p.s.s. для того чтоб получить максимально развернутый ответ лучше почитать какую-то книжку по оптимизации/рефакторингу кода

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Излишняя зависимость между модулями приложения приводит к очень печальным последствиям, когда необходимо что-то изменить в работе программы. Если минимизировать межмодульную зависимость, то сопровождать и изменять приложение будет очень легко, с низкими трудозатратами. Ну и можно будет использовать модули, в других программах.

Лучшее - враг хорошего. Поэтому все нужно использовать в меру, то что может отлично работать в одной ситуации, может вовсе не подойти для другой...

Answer (score 1):

*(Лучше, чем на [вики,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_science)) не напишешь)*

> Tightly coupled systems tend to exhibit the following developmental characteristics, which are often seen as disadvantages:
>
> - A change in one module usually forces a ripple effect of changes in other modules.
> - Assembly of modules might require more effort and/or time due to the increased inter-module dependency.
> - A particular module might be harder to reuse and/or test because dependent modules must be included.